Why MariaDB ignores index when running UPDATE where the indexed column is compared to a subquery?
I have a table (that is very wide, which may or may not be relevant) that I want to update all the records that match something. I pre-calculated the matches and create a temporary table with the list of primary keys of records I need updated - but the UPDATE query is very very very slow (I cancelled it after minutes).
Running EXPLAIN gets me these two weird results:
> explain extended UPDATE my_data set status = 'broken' where id = (select 1711016 as id);
select_type  |SIMPLE     
table        |my_data   
type         |range      
possible_keys|PRIMARY    
key          |PRIMARY    
key_len      |4          
ref          |           
rows         |1          
filtered     |100.0      
Extra        |Using where

> explain extended UPDATE my_data set status = 'broken' where id in (select id from temp_data_updates);
select_type  |PRIMARY    
table        |my_data   
type         |index      
possible_keys|           
key          |PRIMARY    
key_len      |4          
ref          |           
rows         |9030625    
filtered     |100.0      
Extra        |Using where

The 9M figure is the total number of rows in the table. The temp "updates" table has very few rows - as few or a hundred or as few as 1, but regardless the update seems to scan the entire table - and takes forever to complete. An update that targets a single ID - for example using the query in the first explain - completes almost immediately.
I'm using ab InnoDB table - here's a truncated SHOW CREATE:
CREATE TABLE `my_data` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `field_a` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `field_b` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_c` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_d` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_e` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_f` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_g` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `field_h` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `field_i` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_j` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_k` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_l` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_m` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_n` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_o` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_p` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `error` text DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  -- some more keys and constraints
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11310160 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci

Any idea on what is going wrong and how to get my updates to use the primary key index?

Does it make any difference if you apply FORCE INDEX , explain extended UPDATE my_data FORCE INDEX (PRIMARY) set status = 'broken' where id in (select id from temp_data_updates);. From experience if your conditions match more than 20% of the table optimizer chooses a table scan rather than index usage

Nope - the explain looks the same: nothing in possible_keys and rows counts all the table rows. There's no chance that the actual match on the actual table content matches 20% of the records, as the temp table is insignificantly small compared to the data table.

Does the where id in (select id from temp_data_updates) exceeds 20% of the total of the  records of my_data table ?

As mentioned above - no, it can't. id is unique.

no, it can't. id is unique, run  select count(*) from my_data; and select count(*) from my_data where id in (select id from temp_data_updates); and post the results

Running ... where id in ...  is unreasonably slow and this is production db, so I won't let it run to completion - but id in temp_data_updates is a subset of the primary key values from my_data (it was created by selecting from that table) and so select count... where id in... would return the number of rows in temp_data_updates - which at the time of the explain in the OP is: 1. The number of rows in my_data is also listed in the OP.

Use JOIN instead of WHERE column IN (subquery). In my experience, MySQL doesn't optimize the latter well, and MariaDB inherited this.

Look in the docs how to write a multi-table Update, then do what Barmar suggests.

Note EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON shows a bit more information, and optimizer trace to show the process of consideration of the query plan.
